# Shiny for python ui.output_text_verbatim font size

Tags: python, py-shiny

how do you change the size of the output of ui.output_text_verbatim in shiny for python?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily by using [Global Styling](https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/ui-styling.html#global-styling) in shiny apps just by inspecting the CSS class name and style that class with your own css.

Here's is a Shinylive example:

[Bigger Text Verbatim example](https://shinylive.io/py/editor/#code=NobwRAdghgtgpmAXGKAHVA6VBPMAaMAYwHsIAXOcpMAMwCdiYACAZwAsBLCbJjmVYnTJMAgujxM6lACZw6EgK4cAOhFVpUAfSVMAvEyVYoAcziaaAGyXSAFKqYODHDGRMsMLMtgtw7ERwFMymDBof6BDh6c3AC0FAAeZDHECmSoqUwg9hGBNKRJLBwAXnBMiEwWUHSm2TmOAL61gaEhIeEOAJR4TYZc6WSaLBYcsnR2kMESwQByk0wADBIAjPOLTABM8109zilpqZoJAwBucgBGUGR842SJwdsQHarPELI0rHKnY32pEnv9EhYcBYhVIHUQTQAAv9UlCpK85C44Hd2kw3kxbmQbOCmgEpGQFHR-DRghAAFTrXgsTI-MgYCDYphkjaNNovDR6UToGwabQcQGfORPCBgeoAXSAA)

I hope this helps.